# How do you perform a shift keys with tilde key together in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How do you perform a shift keys with tilde key together in PowerShell?

I tried the following and it's not working:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("+{`}")

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("+`")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("+~")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("+{~}")
```

Answer (score 1):

nvm; I have to use the start-sleep for 5 seconds. For some odd reason it needed that extra sleep to perform [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("+{~}")